# How to define the return type of @RestControllerAdvice in Spring Boot 1.5

Tags: spring-boot, error-handling, spring-restcontroller

We are building a RESTful API with several `@RestController`s  which return all kinds of objects including byte arrays (actually application/pdf).

When an exception occurs we handle those with `@RestControllerAdvice`s which return a custom `ErrorView` object. Still spring insists of rendering those as application/pdf which of course is not possible. The client is sending application/json in the accept header but this does not seem to help. Any pointers how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made a mistake which I think I should share.

Basically most of the time the content type negotiation between Spring and the client works like a charm. If the client accepts (as is the case for our app) "application/pdf, application/json" then spring will try to work it our for all responses AKA return values from `@RestController` functions. Except, of course, when you **explicitly** tell Spring to only produce a certain type of response e.g. with

```
@GetMapping(value = "render/document/{docId}", produces = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE))
```

After changing this to

```
@GetMapping(value = "render/document/{docId}", produces = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
```

the ErrorView gets rendered as JSON as intended.